# Add subviews without losing focus (firstResponder status) on NSView

Tags: swift, cocoa

How can I add subview without losing firstResponder status?

```
    let scrollAreaRect = self.finalFrame
    let scrolledView = NSView(frame: scrollAreaRect)

    // Inserisco pulsanti di esempio
    for i in 1 ... 10{
        let bt = LevelButton(frame: NSRect( x: 0,
                                            y: i*30,
                                            width: Int(scrolledView.frame.width),
                                            height: 30),
                             name: "Primo Livello",
                             number: 1)
        scrolledView.addSubview(bt)
    }

   scrolledView.resignFirstResponder()    
    scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: scrollAreaRect)
    scrollView.resignFirstResponder()

    scrollView.documentView = scrolledView
    scrollView.contentView.scrollToPoint((NSMakePoint(0, scrolledView.frame.size.height)))

    self.addSubview(scrollView)
```

After run that code in initializer function, the NSView not calls more keyDown handle. How can I reassign firstResponder status to main view? Call resignFirstResponder on all subviews not works.

Comment: Don't call `resignFirstResponder`? Apple says "Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: I've read but I've found no solution how to resign focus

Comment: Why do you want to resign focus? What happens when you remove the `resignFirstResponder`s?